# What does the Javascript expression 'a = a || function() {...}' mean?

Tags: javascript, construct

I'm not sure what this construct means but I've seen it a few times. The example below is from another Stack Overflow question. I'm not sure how to interpret the initial "or" construct itself:

```
Object.keys = Object.keys || (function () {
  var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
      hasDontEnumBug = !{toString:null}.propertyIsEnumerable("toString"),
      DontEnums = [ 
          'toString', 'toLocaleString', 'valueOf', 'hasOwnProperty',
          'isPrototypeOf', 'propertyIsEnumerable', 'constructor'
      ],
      DontEnumsLength = DontEnums.length;
  //etc...
});
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this question because (imnsho) *every* Javascript programmer should understand, at a deep level, this idiom.  Actually using it is your choice, but I think it makes a lot of code look much nicer.

Comment: For cases like those, I prefer `a||(a=b)` over `a=a||b` which looks quite similar and does the same thing, except it doesn't re-assign a to itself when its already truthy, which is sligthly faster. See http://jsperf.com/a-a-b (I'm writing and ran the test from my phone, so it was only benchmarked on Android - but I believe you should see.similar results.with other browsers, unless they optimize it somehow and know there's no need to run `a=a`)

Comment: damn, my phone crashed right after sending the comment, which took forever to type on a mobile phone.. I got my laptop out to write that again, but thankfully it seems like it was submitted after all

Answer (score 21):

`a = a || function(){...}` is an idiom that is very common in Javascript. It relies on two concepts that, while not unique to Javascript, you might not yet be familiar with.

### 1. **Operator short circuiting**

[Operator short circuiting<sup>[wikipedia]</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) is a compiler optimization that was invented to prevent unnecessary evaluation.

To demonstrate this, let us suppose that we want to determine whether a person is a teenager: that is, whether a person has an age inclusively between 13 and 19 years.

```
var isTeenager = person.age >= 13 && person.age <= 19;
```

Now, let us suppose that the code executes and it turns out that the person is younger than 13. The first condition will be evaluated and will return false. Since the program now knows that the the left hand side of the `&&` operator is `false`, and since `&&` requires both sides to be `true` in order to evaluate to `true`, it knows that evaluating the right hand side is pointless.

In other words, the program, having seen that the person's age is not greater than 13, already knows that he is not a teenager and couldn't care less whether or not he is less than 19.

The same sort of principle applies to the `||` operator. Suppose we wanted to know if a person can ride the bus for free: that is, if the person is over 70 years old or is handicapped.

```
var canRideFree = person.age >= 70 || isHandicapped(person);
```

If the person is over 70, the program already knows that he can ride free. At this point, the program does not care if he is handicapped or not and thus does not evaluate the call to the `isHandicapped` function. If, on the other hand, the person was younger than 70, then `canRideFree` would be set to whatever `isHandicapped` returns.

### 2. **Truthy and falsy values**

[Truthy and falsy values<sup>[some random person's blog]</sup>](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript) are the boolean evaluations of objects. In Javascript, every object will evaluate to either a "truthy" or a "falsy" value.

An expression is "falsy" if its value is any of these:

```
false, null, undefined, 0, "", NaN
```

Everything else is truthy.

People take advantage of the fact that a null or undefined variable evaluates to `false`. This means that you can check if a variable exists very easily:

```
if (a) { /* a exists and is not a falsy value */ }
```

### Combining what we know

The `||` operator short circuits and *returns the value of the last expression that it evaluates*. This principle combines with truthiness in this single statement:

```
Object.keys = Object.keys || function() {...}
```

If `Object.keys` is truthy, it will be evaluated and assigned to itself. Otherwise, `Object.keys` will be assigned to the function. This is a very common idiom in Javascript for checking if a value already exists and assigning it to something else if it doesn't.

Some other languages, such as C#, that do not have truthiness, have a [*null-coalescing operator*<sup>[MSDN]</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) that has a similar purpose.

```
object Value = PossiblyNullValue ?? ValueIfNull;
```

In this code, `Value` will be assigned to `PossiblyNullValue`, unless it's null, in which case it will be assigned to `ValueIfNull`.

### [tl;dr <sup>[wikipedia]</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aToo_long;_didn%27t_read)

If you didn't bother to read anything I said above, all you need to know is that `a = a || function() {...}` basically does what this code does:

```
if (exists(Object.keys)) {
  Object.keys = Object.keys;
} else { 
  Object.keys = function() {...};
}

function exists(obj) {
  return typeof obj !== "undefined" && 
         obj !== null && 
         obj !== false &&
         obj !== 0 &&
         obj !== "" &&
         !isNaN(obj);
}
```

Comment: `[]` is not falsy: `!![] === true`

Comment: I'm totally stealing your superscript brackets for link references from now on, can't believe I haven't seen more of that here already.

Comment: Great explanation, but it should also been more specifically explained that expressions with `||` or `&&` returns the first truthy value they find when the expression evaluates to true

Comment: @shesek Thanks for the feedback. I now mention it explicitly, but it still might not appear as important as it should.

Answer (score 4):

This looks incomplete to me, but it seems as if it is a shim for Object.keys. Basically, if the property doesn't exist (in non standards compliant browsers, for example), we implement it ourselves.

The `or` operator will evaluate the second operand only if the first one is falsy. As such

```
alert(false || "Hello, world");
```

Will alert "Hello, world". In this case, Object.keys would be `undefined`, which evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 3):

The `||` basically means: If `Object.keys` is not defined, define it using the expression behind the `||`.

This behavior bases on the JavaScript feature that any variable that is undefined evaluates to `false`. If the variable is `true`, the second expression does not need to be evaluated, if it is `false` it does.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, that code attempts to define the function `Object.keys` if it isn't already defined (or if it's false). The function to the left of `||` will become the function `Object.keys`.

The reason I said "from what I can tell" is that you haven't posted the entire code snippet. Notice that the code after `||` reads `(function(){` instead of just `function(){`. It's possible that the author has set up the function to be self invoking.

If, after the function definition, you see `})()`, then the return value of the function is stored in `Object.keys`. If not, then the function itself is stored there.