# how works boolean operator ||

Tags: javascript, boolean, operators

I usually use this code to see if the argument of a function is undefined or not

```
var = (typeof var != "undefined")? var : "othervalue";
```

but, other uses this boolean operator

```
var = var || "othervalue";
```

However, I have seen that if the value of checking and boolean false argument is not done correctly.

```
// assuming it is false
var = var || "othervalue"; // will be "OTHERVALUE"!!!
```

I need to know what exactly this operator in this context.

Comment: I assume you meant to use one equal sign `=` as an assignment operator?

Comment: This is called [short circuit operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), which is different from strictly logical operators.

Comment: yep...6 a.m., corrected XD....

Comment: This has got to be a dup, if only this was searchable...

Comment: @MattBall: There is http://symbolhound.com/?q=%7C%7C+javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the Javascript expression 'a = a || function() {...}' mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069302/what-does-the-javascript-expression-a-a-function-mean) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378619/javascript-operator and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118575/init-object-in-javascript-using-operator

Comment: Brilliant, gentlemen and/or ladies. Never knew about symbolhound.

Answer (score 2):

It returns the last expression that terminated the condition. It doesn't work the same as checking for `typeof arg == "undefined"`, as any falsey value on the left will jump to the RHS.

Comment: While this works, it seems like an abuse of the language.  By evidence  of the tone of the OP, it fails the Principle of Least Astonishment (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

Comment: @PaulProgrammer it's fairly idiomatic JS.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer JavaScript is missing a lot of things, such as default  argument values. Using this pattern takes away *some* of the pain of not having this in the core (it's coming though).

Comment: Alas, a decade and a half of dealing with languages like C and Java have totally ruined me for the coming wave of application development.

Answer (score 1):

|| operator will return the last expression, if first one is falsely:

```
var test  = first || "second";
// error will be raised, because first variable is not defined

var first;
var test  = first || "second";
// test   = "second", because first is falsely

var first = "first";
var test  = first || "second";
// test   = "first"
```

I always use ternary operator with typeof expression, because it's a really common thing to forget to define some variable:

```
var test  = 'undefined' != typeof(first) && first ? first : "second";
// test   = first if first is defined and true
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a perl style selection for first true (pseudocode below)

```
eat_breakfast = null
eat_dinner = null
eat_lunch = "eating lunch"

myVal = eat_breakfast || eat_dinner || eat_lunch
print myVal
```

would print "eating lunch"

it will set myVal to the first non-null/non-false entity.